# How to specify versions of plugins, such as sonarjs in sonarcloud?

Tags: sonarjs, sonarcloud

I want to use latest version of sonarjs (3.2 at this moment) on sonar cloud, but travis job shows me that version 3.1.1 in use. It seems like sonarcloud versions of plugins can be outdated on a few months. 3.1.1 is useless for me, since my project use flow, which was added to sonarjs at 3.2 version. How can i manually specify which version of sonarjs to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use different version, unfortunately you will need to wait until SonarJS on sonarcloud gets updated. I hope it will happen very soon.

Comment: so sad, i'll wait than